# Are GooglePlayServices APIs free?

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, openstreetmap, osmdroid

This might be a really stupid question.. but I can't find the answer anywhere.
I have an AndroidStudio Java project and I have a OpenStreetMap map. I have to get the user current position and the android developer page tells me that the android.location API isn't reccomended and that I should use the Google Location Services APIs which are much better (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html).... but are they free to use? For what I know Google Maps APIs that use location cost a lot, but what about GooglePlayServices APIs?

I'am really confused.. thanks for any elucidation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the location APIs in Google Play services are free to use

Comment: Apparently it looks like they aren't... at least, you can't use the location services if you don't use a Google Maps map which isn't free from what I understood, dunno about the other services... Can you please specify your statement if you know more about it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Google services terms&conditions, I would say No.
Fortunately, there are alternatives (not as good, but usable).

See: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Features#geocoding-and-reverse-geocoding

Comment: Wait, so you are saying that the APIs are free to use but you can't use them unless you use a Google Maps map, which isn't free? Because I already checked out in the past Google Maps APIs and if I'm not wrong you needed a token to access them (or the map, don't remember), while the GooglePlayServices APIs can just be accessed with a click and its very strange to me that in the official android.location page they recommend Google APIs without specifying that they aren't free to use... but if the terms&conditions say so, well I guess you are right and all of this is just very chaotic